# Why does DataGrid blank row disappears?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, observablecollection

I have a DataGrid bounded to an ObservableCollection.

```
<DataGrid x:Name="substanceDataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding StoredSequences}" CanUserResizeColumns="True" CanUserResizeRows="True" CanUserAddRows="True" SelectionMode="Single" >
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" Binding="{Binding ID}" IsReadOnly="True" >
            <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                <Style>
                    <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextWrapping" Value="Wrap" />
                    <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                </Style>
            </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
        </DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Width="120" >
            <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                <Style>
                    <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextWrapping" Value="Wrap" />
                </Style>
            </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
            <DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
                <Binding Path="NameEnglish" UpdateSourceTrigger="LostFocus"/>
            </DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
        </DataGridTextColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

In my ViewModel I update the database when a new row is added, using OnCollectionChanged.

```
private void OnCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.NewItems != null) // New row added
    {
        BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();
        bw.DoWork += async delegate
        {
            StoredSequences.CollectionChanged -= OnCollectionChanged;
            sequencesDbManager.AddSequence((Sequence)e.NewItems[0]);
            StoredSequences.CollectionChanged += OnCollectionChanged;
        };
        bw.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
}
```

I mention that the database manager is initialized with a reference to the ObservableCollection:

```
sequencesDbManager = new SequencesDatabaseManager(StoredSequences);
```

and the collection is updated inside `SequencesDatabaseManager.AddSequence()`, after the new item is added to the database:

```
private void UpdateCollection()
{
    System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(delegate
    {
        sequences.Clear();
        foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
        {
            sequences.Add(new Sequence
            {
                ID = (int)row["Id"],
                NameEnglish = row["Name (English)"].ToString()
            });
        }
    });
}
```

**The problem is that after adding the new item, the blank row at the end of the DataGrid disappears. How can I avoid this problem?**